# Authentication Required (packagist.org)

Tags: laravel, create-project

Estou tentando criar um projeto em laravel com o comando:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

Porém está exigindo uma autenticação:

```
Authentication required (packagist.org)
  Username:
  Password:
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não lembro de ter me cadastrado nesse site.

Alguém sabe como corrigir isso?

Comment: Está utilizando algum proxy?

Comment: Não estou usando

Answer (score -1):

Passei por isso usando o macOS... só deixei em branco os dois campos (clicando no enter) e depois que apareceu uma mensagem eu cliquei enter de novo. Pronto, ele rodou o composer update